# Add extra option in Karenderia food item

Tags: yii

I have used "Karenderia Multiple Restaurant System". I want to add an extra option to Food item. For that i have done this as bellow.

Added to food-item-add.php

```
<div class="uk-form-row">
  <label class="uk-form-label uk-h3"><?php echo t("Food Type")?></label>  
<div class="clear"></div>

  <ul class="uk-list uk-list-striped">

  <li>
  <?php 
  if(!isset($data['non_veg'])){
    $data['non_veg']='';
  }
  echo CHtml::checkBox('non_veg',
  $data['non_veg']==2?true:false
  ,array(
   'class'=>"icheck",
   'value'=>2
  ))?>            
  <?php echo t("Non Veg")?>
  </li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

After that i have added this in AjaxAdmin.php to FoodItemAdd function, which action in the admin.js

```
'non_veg'=>isset($this->data['non_veg'])?$this->data['non_veg']:1,
```

After that i have added to the table_structure.php to "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  ".$table_prefix."item"

```
`non_veg` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
```

Now, I want to add the option to an item. But i am getting the a ajax error like this

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.error (admin.js?ver=1:290)
    at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at k (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery-1.10.2.min.js
```

Can i know where is the problem to add an option ?

Comment: If it is not understanding, Please message me i will explain.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i have done everything right. But it not saved  in the DB. So i have added a col with the name. Now it is saved.

Thank you.